# When to use vertical and horizontal scaling?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, horizontal-scaling

What are some scenarios where we have to decide whether to go with horizontal or vertical scaling? Also, is there any other alternative of scaling?

Comment: It would be good if you share your use case and problems you are facing because you asked generic question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you’re choosing between horizontal scaling and vertical scaling, you also have to consider what’s at stake when you scale up versus scale out. Horizontal scaling is almost always more desirable than vertical scaling because you don’t get caught in a resource deficit.

Choosing between vertical vs horizontal scaling depends on the application architecture. For instance, applications built using serverless architecture rightly suit horizontal scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling may apply for various kind of resources at various levels. It could be database, message broker, application runtime, etc., The below mentioned approach is in general acceptable but will vary slightly based on the kind of resource we are talking about.

Basically always choose an environment that supports horizontal scaling. But use vertical scaling for satisfying the need of benchmarked base load or a regular load. For any further varying increase or decrease in the load use horizontal scaling so that you can either increase or decrease the resources according to the need.